# How to make an NSMutableString blank

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablestring

If I have an NSMutableString containing a random string, then how do I remove all characters from it so that it becomes an empty string?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
[myMutableString setString:@""];
```

Obligatory [documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000156-setString_).